# Can I upload my Minecraft PE world for others to play in?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My son and I have built a world together on Minecraft PE.  I'd like to upload a copy of the world to a server so that he and his friends can log in any play together within that world.  Then, as we make improvements I'd like to periodically upload an updated version of the world.

Can I do this with a basic Minecraft PE server hosting account?

Comment: give this a go but i will write an answer when i'm home from work

http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-pocket-edition/mcpe-multiplayer/mcpe-servers/1992056-host-mcpe-server-with-your-pc-tutorial

and move your world in to the server and rename the folder to world(use the link below)

http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-pocket-edition/mcpe-maps/mcpe-map-discussion/1984531-android-ios-how-to-upload-your-mc-pe-map

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you purchase Minecraft Realms (https://beta.minecraft.net/en/realms/).
When you create a Minecraft Realm, you have the option to use one of your Singleplayer worlds as a Realms base (it will not harm or delete the map in any way).
Realms is coming to Pocket soon.
UPDATE: Realms is now in pocket!

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that both people have the same wifi name. Then go to options or settings on the mine craft home page. Then turn on the broadcast to LAN button. It Should work now.